# does not recognize query string containing '

Tags: sql

I am querying some data from the database and inserting data. Whenever the user inserts with ' I have a problem that the query does not regconize.

How can I get rid of that? should I use: `string.replace(''', '"')` ? or any other trick?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use stored procedures, and if you can't, look into preventing SQL injection.

Comment: you should use parametrized queries. show your current way to create the command/sql string and we'll suggest something. Is this SQL Server and C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides to what [Xavi López](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611851/does-not-recognize-query-string-containing/7612031#7612031) has posted (and you really should keep that in mind), to have a single quote in a string you need to write two single quotes, e.g.:

```
myString := 'I''m writing an answer';
```

This represents the string `I'm writing an answer`.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using parameterized queries. It's [dangerous](http://bobby-tables.com/) to insert unprocessed user input on a query, it's an open door to [SQL-Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) attacks.

Those are queries in the form

```
SELECT * FROM USERS where USER_ID = ?
```

The value of `?` is set programmatically with a `query.setString(1, userId)` call, and the driver takes care of escaping everything correctly. It's not a burden you want to have on your shoulders.